# how to customize the view in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.5

I am trying to create a car rental site, I lived a problem when the client reserve a car,  the car must be removed from the window of available cars after reservation, I have a table 'cars 'and table' locations', what I want is when the client rent a car, the car must be removed from the list of cars for rent, here are the pages : /view/cars/index.ctp, /view/cars/view.ctp, /LocationsController.php, CarsController.php

```html
view/cars/index.ctp : 

<div class="row">

 <?php foreach ($cars as $car):?>
 
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="">
   <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image($car['Car']['avatar']),
     array('action'=>'view',$car['Car']['id']),
     array('escape'=>false,'class'=>'thumbnail'));?>
   <div class="caption">
    <h5>
     <?php echo $car['Car']['title'];?>
    </h5>
    <h5> 
     Price: $
     <?php echo $car['Car']['price'];?>
    </h5>
                <h5><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Rent a Car'), array('controller'=>'cars','action' => 'view', $car['Car']['id'])); ?></h5>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <?php endforeach;?>
  
  
  and the view/cars.view.ctp :
  
  <div class="cars view">
<h2><?php echo __('Car'); ?></h2>
    <dl>
  <dt><?php echo __('Id'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['id']); ?>
  </dd>
      <dt><?php echo __('Picture'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['picture']); ?>
  </dd>
  <dt><?php echo __('Price'); ?></dt>
  <dd>
   <?php echo h($car['Car']['price']); ?>
  </dd>
  
 </dl>
    </div>
    <?php 

echo $this->Html->image("cars/".$car['Car']['id'].".jpg", array(
    "alt" => "Cars",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'locations', 'action' => 'add', $car['Car']['id'])
));

 ?>
  
  //and the CarsController : 
  
  
  <?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
 
class CarsController extends AppController {

 
 public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');

 public $helpers = array('Js', 'GoogleMap');


 
 public function view($id = null){
  if (!$this->Car->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid car'));
  }
  
  $options = array('conditions' => array('Car.' . $this->Car->primaryKey => $id));
  $this->set('car', $this->Car->find('first', $options));
   
 }

public function index() {
  $this->set('cars', $this->Car->find('all'));
 }

}


//and the LocationsController


<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class LocationsController extends AppController {


 
 public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');
 public $helpers = array(
  'Js',
  'GoogleMap'
  );

 public function index() {
  $this->Location->recursive = 0;
  $this->set('locations', $this->Paginator->paginate());
 }


 public function view($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Location->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  $options = array('conditions' => array('Location.' . $this->Location->primaryKey => $id));
  $this->set('location', $this->Location->find('first', $options));
 }


 public function add($car_id) {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
   $this->Location->create();
   if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  }
   $users = $this->Location->User->find('list');
  $agencies = $this->Location->Agency->find('list');
  /*$cars = $this->Location->Car->find('list');*/
  $this->set(compact('agencies'));
  $this->set('car_id', $car_id);
  
   
  





 }


 public function edit($id = null) {
  if (!$this->Location->exists($id)) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
   if ($this->Location->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
   }
  } else {
   $options = array('conditions' => array('Location.' . $this->Location->primaryKey => $id));
   $this->request->data = $this->Location->find('first', $options);
  }
  $users = $this->Location->User->find('list');
  $agencies = $this->Location->Agency->find('list');
  $cars = $this->Location->Car->find('list');
  $this->set(compact('users', 'agencies', 'cars'));
 }


 public function delete($id = null) {
  $this->Location->id = $id;
  if (!$this->Location->exists()) {
   throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid location'));
  }
  $this->request->allowMethod('post', 'delete');
  if ($this->Location->delete()) {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location has been deleted.'));
  } else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('The location could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
  }
  return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how i put a condition : if ['Location']['status']=='0' : show car else if 'status' !==0 removed car, i want to know how to do this, and how to read data table Location in the Cars View

Comment: One car can't be rented at the same time in multiple locations. After the client sends a request to reserve a car, your application must change the status to unavailable. Your model cars must have a field: status, not location model. What is the relation between the models, Car and Location?

Comment: okay i will create a field in status, and the relation between car and location : one car has many locations, thnx for your help